# Cannot match any routes: angular rc5

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

From current module if click the link its taking step1/personinvolved. I want it to navigate directly yo /personinvolved.

I have used routerLink = "personinvolved" from step1 page. And step1 and personinvolved has different router and its imported in app.module.

How can I avoid it taking step1 in url. Please suggest

step1 current page link is below

```
<a href="javascript:" routerLink = "personinvolved" title="Can you describe the vehicles involved?" class="person-involved-vehicle-involved">Can you describe the vehicles involved?</a>
```

person module is below .

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { personRouting } from './person.routing';
import { PersonInvolvedComponent } from './personinvolved.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        CommonModule,
        personRouting
    ],
    declarations: [
        PersonInvolvedComponent
    ]
})

export class PersonModule {

}
```

person routing is below

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { PersonInvolvedComponent }    from './personinvolved.component';

const personRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'personinvolved',  component: PersonInvolvedComponent }
];
export const personRouting: ModuleWithProviders =     RouterModule.forChild(personRoutes);
```

app module is below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';

import { HomeModule } from './modules/home/home.module';
import { Step1Module } from './modules/step1/step1.module';
import { PersonModule } from './modules/person/person.module';

import { GlobalService } from './services/global.service';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
     BrowserModule,
     HttpModule, 
     routing, 
     HomeModule,
     Step1Module,
     PersonModule
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    AppComponent
   ],
  providers: [ GlobalService, HTTP_PROVIDERS ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Please find the code now

Comment: What component contains the routerLink?

Comment: link is in step1 module. so its navigating to step1/personinvolved

Comment: Does `routerLink = "/step1/personinvolved"`, `[routerLink]="['personinvolved']"`, or `[routerLink]="['/step1/personinvolved']"`work?

Comment: routerLink = "personinvolved" in anchor tag

Comment: platform-browser.umd.js:937 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'step1/personinvolved'    this is the error im getting once I click the person link in step1 page

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Got any answer ?